# Cache manifest - edited pages not updating

Tags: wordpress, html5-appcache

I have a problem with using the appcache.

I have it working, but it is working too well. I am using it on wordpress and the problem is that the browser is serving up the cached pages so when I update/edit a page and view it in the browser it shows me a page which is cached and not the newly updated one (no number of times refreshing the page helps).

Is there a way to force the browser to use non-cached pages when online?

My cache manifest file is as so:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#
# Version Control
# version 3 
#
CACHE:
/assets/css/app.css
/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css
/assets/css/bootstrap.css
/assets/js/main.js
/assets/js/plugins.js
/assets/js/vendor/jquery-1.8.2.min.js
/assets/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js
/assets/NRClogo_small.png
NETWORK:
*
FALLBACK:
```

All I need is that the pages when edited update. Is there a way of using javascript to force a reload of the manifest, or to have a fresh load of the manifest everytime a user hits the site? Perhaps adding a time expire of every 5 minutes or something?
-Although the manifest will still be the same so it won't update and will still show the cached pages.

Any help would be great and appreciated, and if I am not clear on anything or more info would help please let me know.

Many thanks in advance.

Ali.

Answer (score 1):

This will prefer the online version of things when your'e online:

```
SETTINGS:
prefer-online
NETWORK:
*
```

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response!! Appreciated.

I have tried your solution out but it doesn't seem to be working. I added the 

SETTINGS:
prefer-online

above my NETWORK call (above the wildcard *) in my manifest file but nothing. Still seeing cached pages. I updated my version number too so the browser would know a new download of the file was due.

Could a javascript call of windowevent.update() work?

Comment: Hello I would just like to add, that for some reason my .appcache file is throwing up errors in manifest-validator.com when I add in the SETTINGS:prefer-online

http://XXXX/SETTINGS:
Line 36: Resource not found
http://XXXX/prefer-online

It seems to be seeing a absolute URL that infront of them that isn't there! Any ideas on that? Without the SETTINGS it validates properly.

Comment: It looks like I was reading this in WHATWG's specs and untill it is added to W3C's specs it won't be in the validator.
But that doesn't mean that it might not be implmented in today's browsers.

Comment: iOS 6.0.1 has te same issue, seems that in 6.1 beta the bug was fixed